# orientation-preserving subgroup of crystallographic space group

Tags: group-theory, crystallography

Let $G$ be one of the 230 crystallographic space groups and $G_0$ be the subgroup of orientation-preserving elements. Is it always true that $G_0$ is also one of the 230 crystallographic space groups?

If so, is there a table that gives the correspondence?